# Change button style in Sweet alert

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, sweetalert

I am using SweetAlert Dialog for android.

https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog

In the success dialog, I want to remove to the OK Button and Change its style. Please explain how can I remove the OK button.

I am calling method on button click

```
new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
    .setTitleText("Good job!")
    .setContentText("You clicked the button!")
    .show();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use simple strategy to access the button from **sweet alert**

```
SweetAlertDialog alertDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);
alertDialog.setTitleText("Good job!");
alertDialog.setContentText("You clicked the button!");
alertDialog.show();

Button btn = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm_button);
btn.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(UserSignupActivity.this,R.color.colorPrimary));
```

after accessing you can **style or you can hide** your button as you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can change colors from color.xml to hex values you want;

```
    <color name="blue_btn_bg_pressed_color">#96BFD2</color>
    <color name="blue_btn_bg_color">#AEDEF4</color>
    <color name="button_text_color">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="error_stroke_color">#F27474</color>
    <color name="float_transparent">#00000000</color>
    <color name="gray_btn_bg_color">#D0D0D0</color>
    <color name="gray_btn_bg_pressed_color">#B6B6B6</color>
    <color name="material_blue_grey_80">#ff37474f</color>
    <color name="material_blue_grey_90">#ff263238</color>
    <color name="material_blue_grey_95">#ff21272b</color>
    <color name="material_deep_teal_20">#ff80cbc4</color>
    <color name="material_deep_teal_50">#ff009688</color>
    <color name="red_btn_bg_color">#DD6B55</color>
    <color name="red_btn_bg_pressed_color">#CD5B55</color>
    <color name="success_stroke_color">#A5DC86</color>
    <color name="sweet_dialog_bg_color">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="text_color">#575757</color>
    <color name="trans_success_stroke_color">#33A5DC86</color>
    <color name="warning_stroke_color">#F8BB86</color>
```

Comment: This is awesome, very simple.

Answer (score 2):

This also works

```
SweetAlertDialog sweetdialog = new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
.setTitleText("Good job!")
.setContentText("You clicked the button!")
.show();

 sweetdialog.getButton(SweetAlertDialog.BUTTON_CONFIRM).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this set visibility gone of  OK Button**

```
SweetAlertDialog sweetdialog = new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
.setTitleText("Good job!")
.setContentText("You clicked the button!")
.show();


Button myBtn = (Button) sweetdialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: you have to create the object of **SweetAlertDialog** than you can access ok button

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)`, use the following code.

```
SweetAlertDialog myDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
.setTitleText("yourtext")
.setContentText("yourtext2")
.show();

myDialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

more detail [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454609/remove-ok-button-from-sweet-alert-dialog-android):